# List all flutter plugins URLs defined in pubspec.yml?

Tags: flutter

How do I list all flutter dependencies (plugins) URLs defined in the pubspec.yml file while executing "flutter packages get" command using terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you want to see a terminal response with full details use the "verbose" command "-v":

```
flutter packages get -v
```

The response will be a full list and json will all the URLs from the packages:

[image: Flutter Libraries]